# How to get a single byte in a string of bytes, without converting to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have a string of bytes like `str_of_bytes = b'\x20\x64\x20'`, of which I want to extract, say, the second element.
If I do `str_of_bytes[1]`, what I get is the `int` `100`.
How do I just get `b'\x64'`, without having to reconvert the `int` to `bytes`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extract it as a range:

```
str_of_bytes[1:2]
```

Result:

```
b'd'
```

This is the same as `b'\x64'`

Note that I'm assuming you're using Python 3.  Python 2 behaves differently.

Comment: Then I don't understand, why doesn't `str_of_bytes[1]` work in this case? Isn't `str_of_bytes[1:2]` == `str_of_bytes[1]`?

Comment: @KevinGuan check this in python 2 vs 3: ```print(str_of_bytes[1:2], type(str_of_bytes[1:2]))``` and ```print(str_of_bytes[1], type(str_of_bytes[1])) ```

Comment: @KevinGuan In Python 3 they're not the same.  Using a single index value results in an `int`, as OP noted.  A range, on the other hand, produces `bytes`.

Comment: this solves the problem. Although I wonder: is this the best way to efficiently handle single bytes? I'm working with the `bytes` type because I though it to be more efficient than converting the values to `int`, is this true?

Comment: I think the main motivation for `bytes` is to be able to perform I/O on files without  imposing a character string interpretation on the data.  They are basically packed arrays of small (byte-sized) integers (in the range 0-255, i.e. 8-bit data).  They are memory-efficient, but if you actually want to interpret or manipulate the data (other than a simple copy), you will want to unpack it.